# <img> in markdown tables in github pages

Tags: markdown, github-pages

I have a markdown file here which is rendered properly when viewed within github:

```
## Title
a | b | c
- | - | -
1 | 2 | 3
```

But it's broken when published as github page.
The solution was to add a newline after the title:

```
## Title

a | b | c
- | - | -
1 | 2 | 3
```

How can I fix this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now with an extra newline between the header and the table:
https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/123#issuecomment-317240127